# About the ambiguity of 'where'

Tags: phrase-request

If I ask someone:

> Where did you run last night?

It can be understood either as an enquiry about the place in which that person ran, or as a question about the destination that person ran to.

If I specifically wanted to ask the second question while still using the word *where*, what should I say?

Comment: Or *to where did you run last night?*

Answer (score 1):

Just add the preposition "to" as you did.

> Where did you run **to** last night?

Similarly, you can use "from" to refer to the place they started.

Answer (score 0):

A runner often runs a loop, so "Where did you run" could often be answered "at the local park" (your first version).

If you want to know where they ran *to*, ask it like that: "Where did you run to last night?". The problem with that question is you may confuse a loop-runner: "Um, home?"